# Can UVM flag a bad command line argument?

Tags: command-line-arguments, system-verilog, uvm

I'm using UVM command line arguments to set configuration properties in the UVM hierarchy.

When I pass in a bad config option, I would like to see a `UVM_ERROR` or another failure indication. What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

For example, if I pass in a bad option like:

```
+uvm_set_config_int=bad,mode,5
```

The sim completes, and I do not see any indication from the log that the option was bad:

```
# UVM_INFO @ 0: reporter [UVM_CMDLINE_PROC] Applying config setting from the command line: +uvm_set_config_int=bad,mode,5
```

Full code can be run here: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `uvm_component` that can flag a bad `+uvm_set_config_` option. It throws a `UVM_ERROR` if a bad option was passed in, like:

```
# UVM_ERROR cmd_line_checker.svh(112) @ 0: uvm_test_top.cmd_line_checker [BAD_CONFIG] UVM match for command line config bad,mode not found
```

Full example can be run here: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/766

The code:

```
/**
 * This is a utility class to validate command line arguments in the form:
 * +uvm_set_config_int=<inst_name>,<field_name>,<value>
 * +uvm_set_config_string=<inst_name>,<field_name>,<value>
 */
class cmd_line_checker extends uvm_component;

  /**
   * The enable for this checker.
   */
  bit enable = 1'b1;

  `uvm_component_utils_begin(cmd_line_checker)
    `uvm_field_int(enable, UVM_ALL_ON)
  `uvm_component_utils_end

  /**
   * UVM constructor.
   */
  function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction

  /**
   * UVM connect phase.
   */
  function void connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    if (enable) begin
      check_command_line();
    end
  endfunction

  /**
   * Validate all command line arguments in the form:
   * +uvm_set_config_int=<inst_name>,<field_name>,<value>
   * +uvm_set_config_string=<inst_name>,<field_name>,<value>
   */
  function void check_command_line();
    string args[$];
    uvm_root root = uvm_root::get();

    void'(root.clp.get_arg_matches(
      "/^\\+(UVM_SET_CONFIG_INT|uvm_set_config_int)=/",args));
    foreach(args[i]) begin
      check_config(args[i].substr(20, args[i].len()-1));
    end
    void'(root.clp.get_arg_matches(
      "/^\\+(UVM_SET_CONFIG_STRING|uvm_set_config_string)=/",args));
    foreach(args[i]) begin
      check_config(args[i].substr(23, args[i].len()-1));
    end
  endfunction

  /**
   * Check a single command line argument.
   * The instance name and field name should exist.
   * @param cfg the command line argument in the form:
   *     <inst_name>,<field_name>,<value>
   */
  function void check_config(string cfg);
    string split_val[$];
    string inst_name;
    string field_name;
    uvm_root root;
    uvm_component components[$];
    bit match_found;

    uvm_split_string(cfg, ",", split_val);
    inst_name = split_val[0];
    field_name = split_val[1];

    `uvm_info("CHECK_CONFIG",
        $sformatf("checking inst_name:%s, field_name:%s",
          inst_name, field_name), UVM_HIGH);

    // Get every object in uvm hierarchy that matches
    root = uvm_root::get();
    root.find_all(inst_name, components);

    // If object matches inst_name, check whether a match for field_name exists
    foreach (components[i]) begin
      if (match_found) begin
        break;
      end else begin
        uvm_component component = components[i];
        uvm_status_container status = component.__m_uvm_status_container;
        component.__m_uvm_field_automation (null, UVM_CHECK_FIELDS, "");
        if (uvm_has_wildcard(field_name)) begin
          foreach (status.field_array[name]) begin
            if (!(uvm_re_match(uvm_glob_to_re(field_name), name))) begin
              match_found = 1;
              break;
            end
          end
        end else begin
          // No wildcards to match
          match_found = status.field_array[field_name];
        end
        status.field_array.delete();
        if (match_found) begin
          `uvm_info("MATCH_FOUND", $sformatf(
                "UVM match for command line config %s,%s found in %s",
                inst_name, field_name, component.get_full_name()), UVM_HIGH);
          break;
        end
      end
    end

    if (!match_found) begin
      `uvm_error("BAD_CONFIG",
          $sformatf("UVM match for command line config %s,%s not found",
          inst_name, field_name));
    end
  endfunction

endclass
```

SVUnit test for the above `cmd_line_checker` here: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/768

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you mean with a bad configuration option. When you do a uvm_set_config_int, your first two arguments only specify the instance and the field names. There is no requirement that these two actually exist. You're basically just putting this configuration option in the config DB to be accessed later.

What you probably want is to put a check in your agent that makes sure that it is actually passed a value for its 'mode' field.

```
class my_agent extends uvm_agent;

  //...  

  function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    if (!uvm_config_db #(int)::get(this, "", "mode", mode))
      `uvm_fatal("CFGERR", "Agent was not passed a config")
  endfunction

endclass
```

I tested this on EDAPlayground with your code, but I'm not sure if it got saved.

Comment: Sounds like there is no automatic global UVM check to make sure the instance/field names actually exist, which is what I'm looking for. To save your own copy of someone else's code on EDA Playground, click `Copy` and you'll get a new web link. Then, to re-save it again click `Update`

Answer (score 0):

UVM can output additional information on configuration settings using the static `uvm_component::print_config_matches` bit.

In the example, set the following in your testbench:

```
uvm_component::print_config_matches = 1;
```

For a "good" configuration setting, you will see the following in the output:

```
# UVM_INFO @ 0: reporter [UVM_CMDLINE_PROC] Applying config setting from the command line: +uvm_set_config_int=*,mode,5
# UVM_INFO @ 0: uvm_test_top.my_agent [CFGAPL] applying configuration settings
# UVM_INFO @ 0: uvm_test_top.my_agent [CFGAPL] applying configuration to field mode
# UVM_INFO testbench(40) @ 0: uvm_test_top [my_test] Running test with mode 5
```

For a "bad" configuration setting, you will see the following in the output:

```
# UVM_INFO @ 0: reporter [UVM_CMDLINE_PROC] Applying config setting from the command line: +uvm_set_config_int=bad,mode,5
# UVM_INFO @ 0: uvm_test_top.my_agent [CFGAPL] applying configuration settings
# UVM_INFO testbench(40) @ 0: uvm_test_top [my_test] Running test with mode 0
```

So, now you can parse the output and check that that there is at least one `[CFGAPL] applying configuration to field` that follows every `[UVM_CMDLINE_PROC] Applying config settings`.

Modified code example: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/681